# Serializer inheriting from ModelForm and field type/form type

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-rest-framework

I have a serializer (django rest framework) to return model objects on get request:

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
```

After instantiating this serializer in my view, I use serializer.data to return the key/value of all fields:

```
class MyModelAPIView(APIView):    
    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        obj_pk = kwargs.get('pk')
        obj = MyModel.objects.get(pk=obj_pk)
        serializer = serializers.MyModelSerializer(obj)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

This is an example of what is returned in json:

```
{"firstname": "John", "lastname": "doe", "active": true}
```

However, I'm using JavaScript to generate a form out of this (dynamically generated form), and I would like to know what type of field each key/pair value is, so I can generate the form accordingly. I'm trying to subclass ModelSerializer so that the JSON returned would look like this:

```
{"firstname": {"value": "john", "type": "TextField"},
 "lastname": {...},
 "active": {"value": true, "type": "BooleanField"}}
```

This would allow me to generate the right input types in my form. What would be the best way to get this?
There may be an easier way to generate a form dynamically from a JSON response using the Rest Framework that's completely different from this (hopefully less tedious.) If so, I'd also be interested to hear about it!

Thanks,

Comment: One caveat of this technique is that if the field is multiple choice, I'd get the current value only while I need all the values to create my form dropdown dynamically. So, hopefully, there is a more straightforward way of getting a form generated from JSON.

Comment: Side note, any reason why you are not declaring your fields on the serializer?  i.e. ``fields=['firstname', 'last name']`` no need to overwrite the get method for this.

Comment: Not many reasons. I was trying to manipulate the response data in the view, that's why.

Comment: One of the potential solutions I've been looking at is the HTMLFormRenderer, to take care of most of the heavylifting for me. Potential good direction here?

Comment: Two ways of doing this of the top of my head. You could read the fields meta data i..e ``firstname .`get_internal_type()`` or ``model._meta.get_field('firstname').get_internal_type``. Or you could describe the data yourself in the DB and add it as a nested serializer. This would require you to rework your model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of going in the direction of modifying the JSON data. I created a new renderer instead, inspired by the HTMLFormRenderer and JSONRenderer. I loop through data.fields.values generate a json array with objects with label, help text, and actual field in escaped HTML. So my ajax dynamic form can be easily customized and fast.

Answer (score 0):

Example :

Serializer :

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'username', 'email', 'groups')
```

View :

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows users to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

URL Router :

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)

# Wire up our API using automatic URL routing.
# Additionally, we include login URLs for the browsable API.
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
]
```

Have a look at this quick start documentation on the official documentation; http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/

About the rendering of form; Django REST Framework - JSON API
Documentation : http://drf-json-api.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

This is designed to be used as only a renderer and parser and does not provide any additional functionality that may be expected by JSON API.

```
class ExampleView(generics.ListAPIView):
    renderer_classes = (JsonApiRenderer, )
```

settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES": (
        "rest_framework_json_api.renderers.JsonApiRenderer",
        "rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer",
        # Any other renderers
    ),
    "DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES": (
        "rest_framework_json_api.parsers.JsonApiParser",
        "rest_framework.parsers.FormParser",
        "rest_framework.parsers.MultiPartParser",
        # Any other parsers
    ),
}
```

I hope it helped !